# Keep component alive in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using the Creative-Tim [Dashboard](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/vue-paper-dashboard) to develop a small application and I realize the components loaded on each page are destroyed and re-created each time I switch pages from the sidebar.

I use a global Vue Mixin to my application to send and receive MQTT messages. The methods `created` and `beforeDestroy` are called each time I switch panels.

Is there a way to:

- Keep my Mixin alive
- Keep my components data alive

As an example one of my component is a MQTT Widget:

```
<template>
  <Widget :title="title" :subtitle="subtitle" :footer="topic">
      <h1>{{value}}</h1>
  </Widget>
</template>
<script>

import Widget from './Widget.vue'

export default {
  name: 'numeric-widget',
  components: {
    Widget
  },
  props: {
    title: String,
    subtitle: String,   
    topic: String,
    unit: String
  },
  data () {
    return {
      value: '--'
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    // Subscribe method is exposed by a global Vue Mixin
    this.subscribe(this.topic, (topic, payload) => {
      this.value = payload
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Here what happens:

1. Load the page (seeing `--`)
2. Receive a MQTT value (seeing `80 bpm')
3. Switching to another page
4. Method `beforeDestroy` of my Mixin is called
5. Switching back to the dashboard
6. Method `created` of my Mixin is called
7. I see `--` as if I never received any message.

I have seen on many question that using `<keep-alive>` may help. Unfortunately it does not seem to work in my case.

Comment: In what manner did you use `<keep-alive>`, you can only use it on dynamic components or around the `<router-view>` tag.

Comment: You can store the widget data in a global store and reuse it when the component is re-mounted.

Comment: @8bit Right, the `<keep-alive>` works when placed around `<router-view>` but in this case it will keep alive ALL my components. I just would like to keep alive those that use my Mixin.

Comment: @nowox You can include or exclude components which should be cached with `keep-alive`, see [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive)

Comment: whatever "value(80 bpm)" you are getting try to get that before component is created. So that whenever you switch tabs before component is mounted you can write logic inside created function( store "value"). (if keep alive is not working)

Comment: another way is to write a function in "computed" which returns value using async and await(in es6). I think the problem is whenever we make a service call in computed or created it will take some time meanwhile other lines of code will be executed. To overcome this we can use async and await. I hope this could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use  tag if you don't want your components to be destroyed and recreated again. Following links might help.

[vue js docs keep alive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components)

[vue js  keep alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49517443/vue-js-cant-understand-keep-alive)

Comment: As mentioned in my question I have tried to use keep-alive around my components, but it does not work.